# Rank of labels (received 1) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 4)

Tags: tensorflow

I have a `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` called data_queue defined as follows :

```
self.data_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=1024,
                                                    min_after_dequeue=21,
                                                    dtypes=[tf.float32,
                                                            tf.int32],
                                                    shapes=[[221, 221, 3], []],
                                                    name="data_queue")
```

I am able to successfully enqueue data items into it.

The dequeue operation is defined as follows :

```
        [self.batch_images, self.batch_labels] = self.data_queue.dequeue_up_to(self.batchsize)
```

In the above snippet `self.batchsize` is a constant tensor.

The issue starts now as follows :

I want to push these directly to my graph. Just for clarity the first layer of my graph is as follows :

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.batch_images, filters=96, kernel_size=7,
                                     strides=2,
                                     activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                     kernel_regularizer=tf
                                     .random_uniform_initializer,
                                     name='conv1')
```

The last few lines where the error is referenced are :

```
drop2 = tf.layers.dropout(fc2, name='drop2')
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                logits=drop2,
                                                        labels=self.batch_labels,
                                                                  name="cross_entropy_per_example")
```

The error I receive is :

```
line 1709, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    (labels_static_shape.ndims, logits.get_shape().ndims))
ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 1) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 4).
```

1. When I checked the `tf.rank` of `self.images` and `self.labels`, I got the following :

   Labels
   Tensor("Rank:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
   Images
   Tensor("Rank_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

What is the reason for it ?

***NOTE*** I do not want to use `tf.placeholder` and `feed_dict`. I want to connect the `self.data_queue` directly to the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution myself. Just posting it here if someone else needs help with this in the future.

The output of the convolutional layer has to be reshaped keeping batch size the same. This is important because otherwise the fully connected calculations make no sense. 
Unfortunately, the documentation of `tf.layers.dense` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) is quite fuzzy on this and does not do appropriate reshaping itself.

I did the reshaping using `tf.contrib.layers.flatten` and it worked like a charm